# How do you build an RF device-under-test rig to create your own touchstone (s2p) files with a VNA, de-embedded to pins?

Tags: rf, filter, components, impedance, test-equipment

Can you calibrate a VNA to the pins of just any (low-power or passive) component and then generate an S2P to optimize an impedance match with RF simulation software to do whatever you want?

If so, what are the considerations for building such a device-under-test rig so the de-embedding is actually to the pins of the DUT, with minimal or no de-embedding math?

Applications I can think of off the top of my head:

- Amplifier matching at bias voltages different than the datasheet specifies
- Using non-RF relays as RF relays
- Tuning varactor-phase-shifter and varactor-filter behaviors at different bias voltages
- Tuning impedance matches for PIN-diode, FET- and BJT-based RF switches

Are there some components where this type of testing becomes difficult or error prone? Please consider different-sized devices from tiny PIN diodes to big fat relays.

It seems like with a good DUT rig that the sky is the limit for using components outside of their datasheet spec.  What are the important considerations here?

(Please don't try to address testing for spurious emissions unless it can be done as part of the DUT+VNA test rig, because I think that's a whole other topic.)

How do you design a high quality reference standard for calibrating to a reference plane for reliable (and repeatable) results?

Comment: You can calibrate a VNA to any reference plane where you can provide reference standards. The quality of your measurements will depend on the quality of your reference standards.

Comment: @ThePhoton, yep, thats what the question is targeting an answer to.  I updated the bottom of the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you calibrate a VNA to the pins of just any (low-power or passive) component and then generate an S2P to optimize an impedance match with RF simulation software to do whatever you want?

Yes

> If so, what are the considerations for building such a device-under-test rig so the de-embedding is actually to the pins of the DUT, with minimal or no de-embedding math?

If you don't want to do de-embedding math, then the only way to do it is to let your VNA do it all by calibrating to the device plane.

The standard way to do this is to build a calibration fixture with three standards on it, at the electrical length that your DUT will be built onto a board. Use exactly the same connectors, same construction, and if you're being paranoid then board from the same batch, for both cal pieces and the DUT. If you can't control the source of the substrate, then use something well specified like RO4350 rather than something less controllable like FR4. Building the cal pieces on the same physical board as your DUT test board is also good, you don't have to populate the test connectors if it's only going to be a test board.

You have to make two initial decisions, each with its compromises.

1. What medium to use? Microstrip, co-planar (CP), or co-planar with ground (CPWG). Ideally choose the type that you're going to standardise on in your future projects.
2. Put the reference plane at the device pin, the layout pad, or a few mm back from the pad along a 50 ohm line? This will affect how much modelling you have to do for pad and pin parasitics when you (inevitably) want to use a device in a layout other than the precise one it was characterised in.

An S11 measurement on a standard VNA has three complex unknowns that need calibrating, so you need at least three complex measurements to give you enough equations to evaluate them. If the VNA has the math in it to handle them, you can use any three, known, reflection devices.

The simplest is choice is open, short, load. On the plus side, it's wideband, and covers the Smith Chart well, all VNAs will have the math to handle it, and you can solve it by hand if you want to. On the down side, realisation of the load is difficult (tip, 2 x 100 Ω resistors in parallel often work better than one 50 Ω resistor), and the open characteristics have to be approximated, either from tables or field solvers.

Three offset shorts is often used in coaxial calibration kits. It's narrowband, as the Smith Chart coverage varies with frequency, though you can use more offset lengths to cover a wider frequency range. The impedance reference ***is*** the line that's used for the offsets, which is OK for air-line standards, less so for lines manufactured on substrate. The line loss either needs to be estimated from other measurements, or can be computed as part of the calibration results if we measure four offset shorts. Not all VNAs will handle the four offset / unknown line loss case.

Three of four offset opens is perhaps the cheapest and easiest cal suite to make repeatable reflection standards, you could even trim the line down between measurements in a single-line but consumable measurement set, but also involves the largest number of other parameters that have to be estimated and entered.

Answer (score 1):

You must characterize your test fixture and the calibration standards.  One good way to do this is with some software like HFSS.  Usually, at the reference plane, you would like a short, open, load, and through.

Your fixture construction will likely create an “open” that is not really infinite impedance. ( it will likely be capacitive-like) .

Same with your “short”. (It will likely be mostly inductive ).

And, your load will not really be fifty ohms resistive.

If you have a good RF simulator, you can compute the actual impedances of your standards in your fixture at your measurement reference planes, and use those values for your calibration values in the deembedding math.

Of course, it is very important that your fixture be stable and so your measurements are repeatable.  Construction in a machine shop is recommended. If possible, you would want your fixture to have the minimum inductive and capacitive parasitics possible, so you standards are not too weird.

This is a major problem even with coaxial calibrations, especially with the “open”. Real open cal standards are pretty far from on open circuit at very high frequencies, due to fringing fields at the end of an open coax.